# Increase page size, hidden javascript slider appears and then doesn't work

Tags: responsive-design, resize, slider, jcarousel

I'm putting together a site that I want to be responsive to browser re-sizing. The site pulls one set of CSS styles for a page under 768px, another for any window larger than 768px.

I have a javascript slider (jcarousel) beneath my feature video at.    If I open a window larger than 768px (using Chrome), then the javascript slider works fine.  If I reduce the size of the window, the slider is hidden (with a display:none style) and other content is shown. And if I resize the window larger, the slider appears and works fine.

However, and here's my problem ... If I open a browser smaller than 768px, the CSS hides my javascript slider at the start, and shows my other content. But when I resize the window and make it larger (over 768px), the slider doesn't work right.  I'm assuming the javascript and its associated styles need to be "activated" initially. Is there a way to get this working when a smaller window is opened first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. Rather than try and HIDE the div tag for the slider (with display:none), I moved it off the screen using absolute positioning (with a wrapping div tag). This seems to keep the javascript active, while not showing the user anything...

.sliderwrap { width:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:9999; }

I consider this a "sloppy" fix, but it works...

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to simplify things and let CSS control the display of the slider.

In your HTML add a new slider_wrap  class which wraps around the slider

```
<div class="slider_wrap">
    <div class="vidprev">back arrow</div>
    <div id="vidz" class="slider">thunbnails</div>
    <div class="vidnext">next arrow</div>
</div>
```

Then in your CSS add a new media query which hides or displays these new class

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .slider_wrap{   
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried using a wrapping div around the slider (and tried hiding THAT div tag with a display:none) ... Same problem occurs.

Comment: I tried a "workaround" and used...
.sliderwrap { width:100%; position:absolute; top:0; left:9999; }
This way the javascript isn't actually "hidden ... and can be activated without being seen.  This worked.